# Django - export excel make it faster with openpyxl

Tags: django, excel, django-rest-framework

I am using Django restframework and I am trying to export excel. My issue is the process is take a lot of time till it generates the excel file.

The final file have about 1MB with 20k lines and the generation time is about 8 minutes and this does not seem right.
here is the view:

```
class GenerateExcelView(APIView):
    filename = 'AllHours.xlsx'
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Workbook"

    data = Report.objects.all()
    row_couter = 2
    for line in data:
        first_name = line.employee_id
        second_name = line.employee_name
        age = line.description
        ...

        ws['A{}'.format(row_counter)] = first_name 
        ws['B{}'.format(row_counter)] = second_name 
        ws['C{}'.format(row_counter)] = age 
        ...

        row_counter +=1

    response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
    return response
```

There are few more columns... Is it possible to change the process so it is a bit faster?

EDIT: I had wrong indentation of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It tends to help a lot with performance to use prefetch_related on the queryset.
Given a Table with a 100 rows each row having a foreign key to another table in you example the employee. Your loop would fetch the report then for each of the 100 rows the used relations. This is due to the lazy nature of the django ORM. As you can see we are already on at least 100 Queries... not so great.
If you would use:

```
data = Report.objects.all().prefetch_related('employee')
```

It would use one db query in stead of a hundred.
That should improve the speed of your solution by quite a bit already.

see more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: I tried what you suggested. And I get almost the same time. I think the issue will be in the forloop where are the data pushed to the excel sheet.

Comment: could you extend your example so its more clear what you do inside the loop?

Comment: I had wrong indentation of the loop. Now it is correct.

Comment: I mean i was expecting at least a get like you see in the docs here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

Answer (score 1):

I have been wrestling with the same problem, and even after refactoring into raw SQL there is little improvement. The issue is the speed of openpyxl.

Their documentation suggests that using write-only mode helps, but I found it to be a small improvement at best: my benchmark on a report with 2 tabs, 18k rows on the second tab, showed a 50% reduction after the query refactor to SQL plus an openpyxl refactor to use write-only mode (which is a pain if you are doing cell formatting or special rows like headers and totals).

You can check their performance page here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance.html

... but I wouldn't get your hopes up.